# MVC table grid post form and read line by line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, post, grid

I have a table grid (in the web form) and action result.

```
<form action="ActionStockNew" method="post" id="form">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[0]StockId" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[0]Amount" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[0]Price" /></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[1]StockId" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[1]Amount" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[1]Price" /></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[2]StockId" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[2]Amount" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="f[2]Price" /></td>
       </tr> 

       ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Action result;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionStockNew(FormCollection f)
{
   foreach (var key in f.AllKeys.Where(q => q.StartsWith("f")).ToArray())
   {
      string abba = f[key];
   }

   return View();
}
```

How can read the posted grid data line by line.

For example first row data;

```
f[i]StockId
f[i]Amount
f[i]Price
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a Model for `Stock` and it can be bind to your view. Then you can pass list of stock objects to controller as below.

**Stock Model**

```
public class Stock
{
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Stock>
<form action="/Controler/ActionStockNew" method="post" id="form">
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="[@i].StockId" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="[@i].Amount" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="[@i].Price" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**Controllers**

```
public ActionResult ActionStockNew()
{
    List<Stock> stockList = new List<Stock>();
    // fill stock

    return View(stockList);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionStockNew(ICollection<Stock> stockList)
{
    // process
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is this possible with form collection? I dont want to create stock model.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the data by row index?

Comment: Yes get the data line by line without stock model.

Comment: Are you looking for `f["f[0]StockId"]`, `f["f[0]Amount"]` and `f["f[0]Price"]` ? Likewise you can get the values for second and third rows.

Comment: Yes, approximately. But in for loops f["f["+i+"]StockId"] ...
In fact, model method is much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, we normally use that method instead of FormCollection in MVC.